# What is the default C -std standard version for the current GCC (especially on Ubuntu)?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, c99, c11

When I ask to see the current version of cc I get this.

```
$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$
```

What I would like to know is which of c89, c90, c99 or c11 is being used.

Comment: C89 and C90 are exactly the same language. The 1989 ANSI C standard and the 1990 ISO C standard differ only in some of the (non-normative) introductory material and the renumbering of the sections. The C99 and C11 standards were originally released by ISO and then adopted by ANSI. (The term "ANSI C" still tends to refer to C89/C90, though officially C11 is the current ANSI standard.)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This is explained in depth in the gcc manual, available (if it's installed) by typing `info gcc` or online [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).  The relevant section of the current
manual is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html), but it may or may not correspond to the version you're using.

Some of this information has changed since I posted this answer in 2013, and will continue to change. If you're reading this around 2023, the current version is probably `-std=gnu17` (C17 with GNU-specific extensions; C17 is a minor update to C11). You should check the documentation for the version you're using. The C23 standard has not yet been released, but should be out Real Soon Now. I can't predict when gcc will switch to `-std=gnu23` as its default. If you're reading this in the distant future, let us know how things turned out.

gcc releases from 3.0 to 4.9.4 default to `-std=gnu89` or `-std=gnu90`.
gcc releases from 5.5 to 10.4 default to `-std=gnu11` (they skipped `-std=gnu99`, though you can still specify it).
gcc releases 11.3 and 12.2 default to `std=gnu17`.

---

By default, gcc does not conform to any of the ANSI/ISO C standards. The current default is equivalent to `-std=gnu17`, which is the 2017  standard with GNU-specific extensions. (Some diagnostics required by the language standard are not issued.) Earlier releases of gcc have defaulted to `-std=gnu90` or `-std=gnu11`.

If you want standard conformance, you can use any of the following:

```
-std=c90 -pedantic
-std=c99 -pedantic
-std=c11 -pedantic
-std=c17 -pedantic
```

`-std=c90` can also be spelled `-ansi`, `-std=c89`, or `-std=iso9899:1990`.

`-std=iso9899:199409` supports the C90 standard plus the 1995 amendment, which added a few minor features (all of which are also in C99).

`-std=c99` can also be spelled `-std=c9x` or `-std=iso9899:1999` (the name `c9x` was used before the standard was published). C99 support is [not quite complete](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html), but it's close.

`-std=c11` can also be spelled `-std=c0x` or `-std=iso9899:2011` (the name `c0x` was used before the final standard was published; it was wrongly assumed that `x` would not exceed 9). C11 support is also incomplete; the current status is [summarized here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status).

The `-pedantic` option causes gcc to print required diagnostics for violations of constraints and syntax rules. In some cases, those diagnostics are merely warnings -- and there's no easy way to distinguish between those warnings and other warnings that aren't required by the language. Replace `-pedantic` by `-pedantic-errors` to cause gcc to treat language violations as fatal errors.

A quick history of the standard:

- C89 was the first official C standard, published by [ANSI](http://ansi.org/) in 1989.
- C90 was the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/home.html) version of the standard, describing exactly the same language as C89. ANSI officially adopted ISO's version of the standard. There were two Technical Corrigenda, correcting some errors.
- C95 was an amendment to C90, adding a few features, mainly digraphs and wide character support. As far as I know, a merged version was never published.
- C99 was issued by ISO in 1999. There were three Technical Corrigenda.
- C11 was issued by ISO in 2011. There has been one Technical Corrigendum, fixing the definitions of `__STDC_VERSION__` and `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`.
- C17 was issued by ISO in 2017, and was only a minor update to C11.
- C23 will be issued in 2023. (As I write this, it's close to being finalized, but the document is still being edited.)

ANSI did not issue its own versions of the 1999 or later standards, adopting the ISO standards instead.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is a freely available draft of the C99 standard, with the 3 Technical Corrigenda merged into it.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is a freely available draft of the C11 standard. There are some minor differences between it and the published C11 standard, plus one Technical Corrigendum. For more details, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737472/827263) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8631228/827263).

Comment: Regarding differences between N1570 and C11, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8631228/95580. There were no differences: they even forgot to update `__STDC_VERSION__` and `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`! (This was fixed in Cor 1:2012; see [stackoverflow.com/q/13914050/95580](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13914050/95580).)

Comment: @J.C.Salomon: In fact there was one semantically significant change. I've updated the last paragraph of my answer to link to the same question you linked to, and to my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson can we dare to ask for a 2021 update? C17 and perhaps "C23, so far". Thanks.

Comment: @ChefGladiator It's still "C2X" at the moment. Not sure if 2023 was the original intended year, but I've seen no sign of them aiming for that one in particular.

Comment: @ChefGladiator The default for GCC 9.4.0 (Ubuntu default) is gnu11. GCC 12.1.0 has gnu17 by default. (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Standards.html#C-Language)

Comment: The current default C version as of gcc 13.0.1 is `-std=gnu17`, which is C17 plus GNU extensions. C17 has no new features over C11; it's just a collation of corrections to defects in the C11 standard. These corrections are also applied when gcc targets C11.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum Not exactly current, since gcc 13 hasn't been released yet, but it should be out Real Soon Now.

Answer (score 39):

useful information from `info gcc` for gcc6 and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards for gcc5

#### gcc version `6.3.1` - `10.1.0`

```
2.1 C Language
==============
 The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is
'-std=gnu11'.

2.2 C++ Language
================
 The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is
'-std=gnu++14'.
```

#### gcc version `5.4.0`

```
2.1 C Language
==============
The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu11

2.2 C++ Language
================
The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++98
```

For **C**, default mode remains `std=gnu11`, but for **C++** it has jumped from `std=gnu++98` to `std=gnu++14`

Comment: This answers the question.

Comment: Looks like it's `gnu17` for gcc 10.2

Answer (score 20):

**Minimal test program**

If you feel like finding it out empirically without reading any manuals.

c.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef __STDC_VERSION__
    printf("__STDC_VERSION__ = %ld \n", __STDC_VERSION__);
#endif
#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__
    puts("__STRICT_ANSI__");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Test with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for std in c89 c99 c11 c17 gnu89 gnu99 gnu11 gnu17; do
  echo $std
  gcc -std=$std -o c.out c.c
  ./c.out
  echo
done
echo default
gcc -o c.out c.c
./c.out
```

Outcome:

```
c89
__STRICT_ANSI__

c99
__STDC_VERSION__ = 199901
__STRICT_ANSI__

c11
__STDC_VERSION__ = 201112
__STRICT_ANSI__

c17
__STDC_VERSION__ = 201710
__STRICT_ANSI__

gnu89

gnu99
__STDC_VERSION__ = 199901

gnu11
__STDC_VERSION__ = 201112

gnu17
__STDC_VERSION__ = 201710

default
__STDC_VERSION__ = 201710
```

Conclusion: `gnu17` is used by default:

- `__STRICT_ANSI__`: GCC extension that is defined for `-std=c` but not for `-std=gnu`, see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html
- `__STDC_VERSION__`: C99+ ANSI C macro that set for each version. Not present in C89 where it was not yet defined by the standard.

For an explanation of `-std=gnu*` vs `-std=c*` see also: [What are the differences between -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11)

**C++**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
#ifdef __cplusplus
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
#endif
#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__
    std::cout << "__STRICT_ANSI__" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Test with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for std in c++98 c++11 c++14 c++17 gnu++98 gnu++11 gnu++14 gnu++17; do
  echo $std
  g++ -std=$std -o cpp.out cpp.cpp
  ./cpp.out
  echo
done
echo default
g++ -o cpp.out cpp.cpp
./cpp.out
```

Outcome:

```
c++98
199711
__STRICT_ANSI__

c++11
201103
__STRICT_ANSI__

c++14
201402
__STRICT_ANSI__

c++17
201703
__STRICT_ANSI__

gnu++98
199711

gnu++11
201103

gnu++14
201402

gnu++17
201703

default
201402
```

Conclusion: `gnu++14` is the default:

- `__cplusplus`: macro defined by the C++ standard including on C++98 onwards

Tested on Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/f9a63634242de7a27dc84b880e0018f55d5aac8a/gcc-std-default).

Comment: What's the difference between `gnu17` and `c17`?
Is there much difference?

Comment: @RaviRaj `gnu*` is `c*` + all GNU language extensions, there must be a few dozen of them, `c*` is strict ANSI, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to query [C++ version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735016/5447906) and adapted it for C:

```
gcc -dM -E -x c  /dev/null | grep -F __STDC_VERSION__
```

Answer (score 3):

The first line will give your GCC version (4.7.2)

> (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

When you compile your code, you can specify which C/C++ revision you want to use, by adding `-std=c99` or `-std=c99`  ...

Note `gnu89` is used by default.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of, the -std= option to gcc can not be used to "sandbox" the compiler into not supporting constructs from later versions of standard C.  This is true with or without `-pedantic`

You can not depend upon on `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic` to give you errors or warnings if you try to compile using some C99 code constructs.  In some cases it will, in others it will not.  For example, it will happily compile code that uses the `%zu` format specifier in a printf() call, even though it wasn't added until C99.

Comment: For that specific example, it is because `printf` is a library function and technically, the compiler doesn't care. Although many compilers do have a lint check for the format string, diagnosing problems here isn't required.

Answer (score -2):

Default gcc command is the GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is the default for C code.