# How to get current c dialect in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, dialect

Newbie in C programming.
In gcc `-std` sets the C standard that compiles, e.g. `gcc -std=c99`.
It's possible to know which C standard is currently set?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737104/what-is-the-default-c-mode-for-the-current-gcc-especially-on-ubuntu

Comment: @ooga You are right, it's exactly the same question. However in all answers there I find how to set the C standard, not how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this program to print the default:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
#ifdef __STRICT_ANSI__
    printf("c");
#else
    printf("gnu");
#endif

#ifdef __STDC_VERSION__
  #if __STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L
    puts("99");
  #elif __STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L
    puts("11");
  #else
    puts("(unknown)");
  #endif
#else
  puts("90");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are various preprocessor symbols that are defined in various modes.  You can use `gcc -E -dM -x c /dev/null` to get a dump of all the preprocessor symbols that are predefined.

When in C99 mode (`-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`), the symbol `__STDC_VERSION__` is defined to be `199901L`.  In C11 mode (with `-std=c11` or `std=gnu11`), it's `201112L`

When in strict C mode (`-std=cXX` as opposed to `-std=gnuXX`), the symbol `__STRICT_ANSI__` is defined to be `1`

Comment: `gcc -E -dM` gives me _gcc: fatal error: no input files. 
compilation terminated._ both in Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: @Salvador: well yes, you need to give the compiler driver at least one input file so it knows which language to compile.  You can give it any existing file, or create an empty one with a `.c` or `.cpp` extension.

Comment: Sorry but newbies need ready to use code as `echo | cpp -dM` that dumps the same predefined preprocessor settings (and doesn't need a file to compile).