# Minimal c11 source code

Tags: c11

I'm starting upgrading my C knowledge from C99 to C11, and I wonder if my compiler is capable by default to understand C11 or I need the `-std=c11` flag; how can I test it with a simple c11 source code not compiling with `-std=c99` flag? There is also the C++11 standard, but I am starting from [this article](https://matt.sh/howto-c) which is only about C.

I tried with some simple code using `auto` declaration, but since it is a valid keyword also in C99 I'm a bit lost and asking here.

After publishing this question I received answers regarding the macro `__STDC__VERSION__`, and also tried the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22975536/971443).

*Surprisingly*, the outputs of my tests were:

```
compile line: gcc main.c -std=c11 -o main.exe
oputput of main.exe: c11

compile line: gcc main.c -std=c99 -o main.exe
oputput of main.exe: c99

compile line: gcc main.c -o main.exe
oputput of main.exe: gnu90
```

The situation is that I can get the compiler capabilities at runtime, but still no at compile time.

For C++ I was able to find this sample code that does compile only with C++11:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = nullptr;
}
```

As the nullptr is only available within C++11.

Comment: Regarding the `auto` keyword, I think you are mixing [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) and [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). C11 did not add any `auto` type deduction, C++11 did. C and C++ are two *very* different languages, they just share some common syntax.

Answer (score 2):

GCC from 4.x-something started to add C11 support. They have gradually added more and more C11 support. But all 4.x versions default to `-std=gnu90`.

GCC from 5.0 and newer should default to `-std=gnu11` and will understand C11. So in order to know what your gcc defaults to, simply check `gcc --version`.

Note that this is not the same thing as standard C. If you want pure standard C, you always have to use `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. I would strongly recommend to always use these two switches, particularly when learning C.

Programatically, you can check which version that the compiler is set to like this:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L
  #error C11 compiler
#if __STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L
  #error C99 compiler
#else    
  #error Sucky compiler
#endif
```

Comment: Although this will denote compilers implementing future standards as Sucky too. You luddite! Btw shouldn't you have two following underscores too or is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @Bathsheba Feel free to add `#if __STDC_VERSION__ > 201112L #error Futuristic compiler #endif`. Indeed there should be 2 trailling underscores, thanks

Comment: But are the version numbers guaranteed to be increasing?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah they are. Though we are gonna get overflow problems and therefore a severe millennium bug in the year 2147483647.

Answer (score 0):

`__STDC_VERSION__` is defined with value `201112L` for C11. C99 has `199901L` as the value.

That will be the most reliable way.

Note that this value will change in future standards and (crediting @Lundin), future version numbers increase monotonically in time.