# Is there a command line involving gcc to know which --std=xxx it is using?

Tags: c, gcc, command-line

I can choose to call

`gcc --std=c99 toto.c -o toto.elf`

But in my case, I would like to know which --std is used by default when calling

`gcc toto.c -o toto.elf`

***Note for closing request:***
*I refute the idea that this topic is a duplicate, in fact, what I want is not only knowing what the default --std is but also what --std is currently used and how make difference between std=gnu11 and std=c11.
Sure that my first post was leading people in error.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default C -std standard version for the current GCC (especially on Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737104/what-is-the-default-c-std-standard-version-for-the-current-gcc-especially-on-u)

Comment: You can find manuals for all released GCC version lines at [the GCC docs site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).  Each one documents the default dialect among the arguments accepted for the `--std` option.

Answer (score 3):

i found this `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep 'STDC_VERSION'`

Comment: the issue with this solution, is that it doesn't make a difference between ```--std=gnu11``` and ```--std=c11```. Both give ```#define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L```

Comment: You may fix that with like `gcc -std=c11 -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep 'STDC_VERSION\|__STRICT_ANSI__'`. `__STRICT_ANSI__` will be defined in non-gnu mode. Also, `gcc -std=c89` will not output `STDC_VERSION` - so when it's missing, it's c89 (or older??).

Answer (score 2):

- Everything prior version 5.0.0 has `-std=gnu90` as default.
- Everything between version 5.0.0 and 8.0.0 has `-std=gnu11` as default.
- Everything past 8.0.0 has `-std=gnu17` as default.

So you only need to check `--version`. However, the `__STDC_VERSION__` should also correspond to the `-std=cxx` even when compiling with GNU extensions.

Comment: According to [its docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options), GCC 10 defaults to `--std=gnu17`.  Versions 8 and 9, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yikes, I'm not up to date then! Thanks.