# Error : 'to_wstring' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, string, tostring, wstring

I don't know why this is not compiling.

```
std::wstring number = std::to_wstring((long long)another_number);
```

Compiler : gcc 5.1.0

IDE : codeblocks 17.12

Comment: are you compiling for c++11?

Comment: Post the actual, exact error. Googling for the error message is a great way to find answers.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ yes

Comment: works for c++11: https://godbolt.org/z/K36PzEY4M

Comment: Apart from that ... gcc *5.1* is a bit [old and unsupported](https://gcc.gnu.org/). So is [CodeBlocks 17.12](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/17.12/). It's quite possible the defaults used by both changed in the last 4 years. Maybe CodeBlocks didn't use C++ 11 by default back then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround

```
std::string temp = std::to_string((long long)number);
std::wstring number_w(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Comment: GCC 5.1 rejects this (correctly). `long long(number)` has to be spelled as `(long long)number` (since `long long` is spelled with more than one word).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this works fine in visual studio

Comment: Visual studio is wrong, see (2) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). And (modern) VS should support `to_wstring` without needing a workaround...

Answer (score 4):

you have to ensure that:

you have included the string header:

```
#include <string>
```

you are compiling with c++11 flag: ***-std=c++11***

> $ g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program

here is the official doc
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring

----and ofcourse, i hope you mean something like

```
 std::wstring number = std::to_wstring((long long)anotherNumber);
```

instead  of

```
std::wstring number = std::to_wstring((long long)number);
```

coz you cant declare **number** and initialize it with a another variable named **number**...

this example [here](https://ideone.com/Rr0nj2) is working fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    auto numberX{2020};
    std::wstring f_str = std::to_wstring((long long)numberX);
    std::wcout << f_str;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In GCC 5.4.0 [the default standard version is `-std=gnu++98`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057210/995714) so I guess it's really the reason

Comment: Thanks.  I was having `std::vector<std::wstring>` fail, `#include <string>` worked.