# Python/Pip C package PyProj fails to compile with GCC

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-errors, pip, proj

I'm trying to install [PyProj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj) on a [WebFaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) VM, via [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) & [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  I'm getting compile errors.  I'm using this command:

```
$ pip install pyproj
```

There's a lot of output, terminating in this:

```
src/geodesic.c: In function ‘InverseStart’:

src/geodesic.c:1093: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/<user>/webapps/<webapp>/env/py34/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ow1vcsjk/pyproj/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cl2pbd20-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/<user>/webapps/<webapp>/env/py34/include/site/python3.4" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ow1vcsjk/pyproj
```

I'm not quite sure where to start.  I gather from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346592/iso-c90-forbids-mixed-declarations-and-code-because-of-arrays-how-do-i-fix-this) the problem lies in compatibility for C90 in PyProj, and I might compile instead against C99.  Just a guess.

As mentioned, this is on a remote VM with shell access.  I have a matching Virtualenv on my dev machine (Mac), which compiles without issue.  However, there are different compilers:

Dev:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
```

VM:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
```

Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the version of GCC on your VM is defaulting to the ISO C90 standard but the pyproj code is incompatible with that.  To force GCC to use C99 instead you need to set the CFLAGS environment variable accordingly, try

```
export CFLAGS='-std=c99'
```

then run `pip install pyproj` again.  I get the same problem with healpy and this works for me.

Comment: I marked this as answered, because this looks like the right answer; I don't have that VM setup anymore to check it, though.  I'll try it again when I get back around to that project, but that might be a while.  Thanks regardless!